# Login page, check the password in the same page

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, header

I was trying to make a login page but I cannot get it working. I have three files:header, login and index page. Here are the codes:
admin_header.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Project</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <body id="home">
<div class="top" id="header">
<ul>

        <li><a class="menu" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="search.php">Add an Artist</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="contact.php">List the Artists</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="contact.php">Add a movie</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="contact.php">List the movies</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="contact.php">Add an admin</a></li>
</ul>


</div>
<?php
 $server = 'localhost';
 $user = 'root';
 $pass = 'blablabla';
 $mydb = 'projectdb';
 $movies = 'movies';
 $artists='artists';
 $roll='roll';
 $users='Users';
 $connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass);
 mysqli_select_db($connect,$mydb)or die("cannot select DB");
session_start();
define('ADMIN',$_SESSION['username']);
if(!$_SESSION['username'])
{
header("location:admin_login.php");
}

?>
</body></html>
```

admin_login:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

    $login_form = <<<EOD
<form name="login" id="login" method="POST" action="">
<p><label for="username">Please Enter Username: </label><input type="text" size="100" name="username" id="username" value="" /></p>
<p><label for="password">Please Enter Password: </label><input type="password" size="40" name="password" id="password" value="" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="reset"/></p>
</form>
EOD;
if (isset($_GET['msg']))
{
$msg=$_GET['msg'];
if($msg!='') 
{
echo '<p>'.$msg.'</p>';
}
}
 //If message is set echo it}

echo "<h1>Please enter your Login Information</h1>";
echo $login_form;
ob_start();


       if (!isset($_POST['username'])||($_POST['password']))
       {
       echo "Please, enter your login information";
       }
       else
       {
       $username = $_POST['username']; 
       $password = $_POST['password'];
 if (!$connect)
       {
       echo ("Cannot connect to $server using $user");
       }
       $username = stripslashes($username);
       $password = stripslashes($password);
       $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$username);
       $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$password);
       $sql="SELECT * FROM $users WHERE username='".$username."' and password='".$password."'";
       $result=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
       $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
       if($count==1)
       {
       session_start();
       $_SESSION["username"]=$username;
       $_SESSION["password"]=$username; 
       header("location:admin_index.php");

       }
       else 
       { 
        $msg = "Wrong Username or Password. Please retry";
        echo $msg;
       }
       }
ob_end_flush();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

admin_index:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
include('admin_header.php');
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

I don't get any error, but I don't get redirected to the index page no matter what data I type. Could you please help?

Comment: `action=""` might be a clue or does it go to the current page?

Comment: If you don't get redirected what happens instead?

Comment: On another note it looks like you are storing the passwords in plain text in your database. You should NOT do this. Instead you should store a hased and salted password in your database. You can read more about this here https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm. Also make sure you use a stronger hash algorithm such as SHA2.

Comment: You're going to find this is troublesome `if (!isset($_POST['username'])||($_POST['password']))` = if $_POST['username'] is not set or $_POST['password'] is truthy. Pretty sure that's not what you want,

Comment: Needless use out output buffering to cover up "headers already sent" error.

Comment: @popnoodles it should go to the same page, I just stay on the same login page even if I type the correct password;how should I change the statement `if (!isset($_POST['username'])||($_POST['password']))`? I am stuck with it as well(

Comment: reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @Strawberry I am trying to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a double `<body>` tag in `admin_header.php`.

Replace

```
...
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <body id="home">
<div class="top" id="header">
<ul>
...
```

With

```
    ...
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
        </head>
        <body id="home">
    <div class="top" id="header">
    <ul>
    ...
```

It may be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

A few problems:

- You are using `header()` calls when you have already outputted text to the browser. That will not work, you need to put all php stuff like `session_start` and `header` calls at the very top of the script, before you output anything to the browser.
- Never ever use plain-text passwords, you should salt and hash them before you store them.

Comment: This wouldn't be the solution to his problem?

Comment: @Loko There are many problems, but the one stated in the question is `I don't get redirected` and the cause of that (one of the causes...) is output before the `header` call.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i donot see the page where you want to submit your data to. the basic idea is, have a .html or .php file which accepts input, and then send those input values to another page for further processing involving validation and entry into database etc. 
An example:

User.html

```
<form name="login" id="login" method="POST" action="authenticate.php">
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="password" name="passwrd"/>
<input type="submit" name="Login" value="login"/>
</form>
```

and then on Authenticate.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Login'])){
$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$pass= $_POST['passwrd'];
// from here on.. you have to also validate the inputs, which could be done with filter_var and then use a password library like Bcrypt available on Github before you send your data to database.
}
?>
```

Secondly,try yo seperate out Models, Controllers and Views.. donot mix and match php and html, it just makes harder to debug things. To print error messages you can send error messages via json datas.

Thirdly, The PHP Manual, Google and Youtube are good to get you through the basics.

Comment: So, I cannot combine two files in one as I did?

Comment: it just makes things difficult. when u have these profile pages or some other pages that are mostly dependent of dynamically generated datas, those will end up with a minimum of 100 lines of php codes, and just imagine for youself, when u add the htmls inside them.. using print_r() s and echos or closing and opening php tags. then your file becomes very messy, a missing semicolon may take a whole day. so my advice, Integrate and Indent .

Comment: like Bumbolt pointed out to <body> tags. These errors are only becoz you combine View with Controller and Model